# How do I add an attribute to a record's primary constructor?

Tags: c#, record

I have a record with an additional convenience constructor:

```
public record PublishedTestMethod(Guid Id, string Name, int Version, string Status, Guid? Publisher,
    DateTimeOffset? DatePublished)
{
    public PublishedTestMethod(TestMethod tm) : this(tm.Id, tm.Name, tm.Version, tm.Status, tm.Publisher,
        tm.DatePublished)
    {
    }
}
```

I would like to deserialize this from a JSON object:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PublishedTestMethod>(json);
```

I get the error:

> Unable to find a constructor to use for type Namespace.PublishedTestMethod. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute.

Ideally, I'd like to assign the `[JsonConstructor]` attribute to the long constructor, as I think this would let it map nicely from the JSON. Adding it to the record itself doesn't work, and I can't see an [attribute target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/#attribute-targets) for a constructor. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'd just make an extension method on TestMethod, that creates the record.

Comment: I've flipped `PublishedTestMethod(TestMethod tm)` to a static method `FromTestMethod` on the record, which avoids the problem. Still, I think it'd be more elegant to be able to keep them both as constructors and mark the first as the one to use for JSON deserialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an attribute on a record or on the primary constructor of a class you can use the method: target like this:

```
[method: JsonConstructor]
public record PublishedTestMethod(Guid Id, string Name, int Version, string Status, Guid? Publisher,
    DateTimeOffset? DatePublished)
{
    public PublishedTestMethod(TestMethod tm) : this(tm.Id, tm.Name, tm.Version, tm.Status, tm.Publisher,
        tm.DatePublished)
    {
    }
}
```

This is a [new feature in C# 12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/primary-constructors#attributes-targeting-primary-constructors).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, what you want is syntactically possible.

What I would have done is something like this:

```
public static class TestMethodExtensions
{
    public static PublishedTestMethod ToRecord( this TestMethod tm )
    {
        PublishedTestMethod myRecord = new ( tm.Id, 
                                        tm.Name, 
                                        tm.Version, 
                                        tm.Status, 
                                        tm.Publisher,
                                        tm.DatePublished);
         return myRecord;
    }
}
```

So, you can just do

```
PublishedTestMethod ptm = myTestMethodInstance.ToRecord();
```